# check if page was redirected or opened directly in php cross-domain

Tags: php, redirect, cross-domain

How can I check if I was redirected from another domain to page or opened directly in right domain?

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the tags, which you assigned that you own an server, running PHP and want to know whether the users, visiting your page are comming from a page belonging to your domain or from somewhere else.
This is normally stored in the **referer** header of an HTTP request.
Try accessing it in PHP with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

The variable should contain the whole path of the source page and you can extract the domain/hostname using `parse_url()`

Complete example:

```
<?php
  $sourcehost = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it but ufortunately, after redirect 301 there is no data stored in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable.